# Creating and using services in drupal6

Tags: drupal-6

i am new to drupal.
 I am currently working on web services. Eventhough i selected REST and XMLRPC servers in services I got the following warning: A library is missing for rest_server to work (Currently using Missing library Please download spyc and create a file called spyc.php in rest_server/lib)
i downloaded spyc and followed the above instruction but it dint worked.
can any one help me to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

put the `spyc.php` inside the services module. (`services/servers/rest_server/lib/`)

Answer (score 0):

try to clear site cache from "Administrator - > Site configuration  -> performance"